# Query to sum up rows value to a specific max value

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a problem that includes 3 tables like this (i show only significative fields):

Table Orders:

```
id
date
```

Each order can have more rows:

Table OrderRows:

```
id
order_id
article_id
quantity
quantity_evaded
quantity_available
```

Now on the order list table i make a query like this to summarize all the value of an order

```
SELECT o.*,
   SUM(r.quantity) quantity, SUM(r.quantity_evaded) evaded,
   SUM(r.quantity_available) available
FROM `Orders` AS `o`
LEFT JOIN `OrderRows` as `r` ON `r`.`order_id`=`o`.`id`
GROUP BY `o`.`id`
```

Now the problem is that this query doesn't tell me nothing about the fact the order can be closed or not. The order can be closed when all the articles in it have enough availability for each row. Let's take the example where i have an order with 2 articles in it, article A and article B, each of them have been ordered in quantity of 5 and the availability are 10 for A and 2 for B.

The sum of availabilities gives 12 (10+2) that is over the quantity ordered that is 10, but i have not enough items for articles B (only 2 on 5 ordered). Is there a way to make the sum in a way that count to a specific max value or the only way i have is to cycles all the rows of the order and check if all the singular rows have enough availability?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do the comparison *before* applying an aggregation function:

```
SELECT o.*,
       SUM(r.quantity) as quantity,
       SUM(r.quantity_evaded) as evaded,
       SUM(r.quantity_available) as available,
       NOT MAX( r.quantity > r.quantity_available ) as is_closed
FROM `Orders` `o` LEFT JOIN
     `OrderRows` `r`
     ON `r`.`order_id` = `o`.`id`
GROUP BY o.id;
```

The expression `r.quantity > r.quantity_available` returns `1` if the order cannot be closed.  The `MAX()` determined if *any* articles meet this criterion.

Note:  This assumes that articles are not duplicated within an order.

Comment: That's great, it works. I'll never be an sql guru, i'd never thought that the max of a comparison could be used of check any row singularly. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Do a cumulative sum result set, then filter on that result set where the sum is less than the quantity available. That will give you the orders that you can fulfill with the available quantity.